# How to reset GoDaddy email password?

Tags: account-recovery, passwords, godaddy

I haven't logged on to my GoDaddy email in several months.  I tried to sign in and got an error message that my password is not correct.  When I tried to "Reset Password", it asks me for my password, so obviously I can't enter that.

Comment: You can contact their support team and you can ask them to reset your password.

Answer (score 1):

- Log in to your GoDaddy account.
- Go to My Products, and next to Workspace Email, click Manage.
- Click the email address you want to edit.
- If you only hover over the email address, you'll get a pop-out window. Here you can click Edit, and continue.
- In the Change password field, enter the new password.
- In the Confirm Password field, re-enter your new password.
- Click Save.

Next Step

It can take up to 30 minutes for your new password to that effect. So, after that time have your user try logging into their email, again.

Answer (score 1):

Advice [here](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/reset-your-godaddy-password-8) is:

> ## Reset your GoDaddy password
>
> If you forgot your GoDaddy account password, you can reset it.
>
> 1. Go to the Password Reset page.
> 2. Complete the on-screen fields, and then click Submit.
>
> Note: If you don't know your username or customer number, click I
>   forgot.
>
> If you cannot complete this form successfully, see this article
>
> You'll receive an email at the address on file with a link to reset
>   your password in a few minutes.

Some of the article referred to, [here](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/submitting-a-change-of-accountemail-update-form-4043), is:

> ## Submitting a Change of Account/Email Update Form
>
> If you cannot access the email address associated with your account
>   and cannot verify the information required for our customer support
>   department to assist you, you can submit a Request for Change of
>   Account/Email Update Form to request an update. Along with the form,
>   we also require:
>
> - Photo ID — A color copy of a government-issued photo identification, such as a driver's license, military ID, or passport
>     (signature must be included).
> - Business ID — If the domain is registered to a business, we also need valid business identification, such as:
>
>   - Business license
>   - Tax certificate
>   - Doing Business As documentation
>   - Fictitious Name documentation
>   - IRS 501(C)3 "Determined Letter"
>   - Government-issued certificate of tax exemption that proves charitable status
>   - EIN/TIN verification letter (IRS Letter 147C)
>
>     1. Visit changeupdate.com and click **Get Started**.
>     2. Enter in the name of the domain you want to access (do not include the **www** when you enter your domain name) and click **Next**.
>     3. Enter your contact information and click **Next**.
>     4. To upload your photo or business ID, select **Upload files now** and click **Browse**, and click **Open** on the appropriate files.
>     5. Enter the access code, and then click **Submit Request**.
>
> We will contact you with more information within 3 days of receiving
>   your photo ID and/or business ID.